# sed mac insert tab and text at specific line

Tags: sed, macintosh

I'm trying to use sed to insert a tab followed by a string with quotes (json) followed by a newline on mac on the second line. So far I've got

```
sed -i '.json' "2i\\
\"$(printf '\t') \"1.0.1\": \"1.0.1.zip\",\\
    " dummy.txt
```

and that outputs

```
"        "1.0.1": "1.0.1.zip",
```

and then when I try to remove the `\"`

```
sed -i '.json' "2i\\
$(printf '\t') \"1.0.1\": \"1.0.1.zip\",\\
    " dummy.txt
```

No tab is there. am i missing something here to get the tab?

Edit:
I tried this

version=5.5.1

```
sed -i '' "2i\\
echo -e [\\t] \"1.0.1\": \"1.0.1.zip\",\\
    " dummy.txt
```

and the output of my dummy.txt file is

```
echo -e [t] "1.0.1": "1.0.1.zip",
```

No tab is present.

Comment: I can't see your problem. "none of them are working" and "does not work" is NOT something that people can build an analysis and meaningful answer on. Please post DATA: input, expected output, error msgs. Looking at  your `sed` command, I can't see you "insert a tab" in it. Is it that you don't know how to include it into the script?

Comment: For your second problem (same: DATA missing), looks like the `$` sign, needed for expansion, is escaped thus useless.

Comment: @RudiC fair enough. I added more description. Sorry if it wasn't clear before. this is my second day into bash so sorry if this is noob.

Comment: JSON does not rely on tabs, nor newlines for that matter. What is the document you are trying to insert this key and value? It would be easier using a JSON processing tool such as `jq`.

Comment: @Kusalananda it's an internal json document. i just thought it'd be nice to format it with sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the single quotes. The shell interprets single quotes as "pass this on verbatim, without interpreting any special characters". You need to replace them with double quotes and escape the double quotes inside the parameter. Something like this:

```
sed -i "2i\\
\"1.0.1\": \"1.0.1.zip\",
   " file.json
```

For your original question, inserting a tab with `sed`, this works (`2i` will insert at line 2, where the first line of the file is 1). If you want to add a tab character in the command line (or in vim), press `Ctrl+Q-<Tab>` to tell it that the tab character is literal and not to be interpreted by the editor/shell. In the case of other editors, look in the editor documentation to see how to enter a literal tab.

The example would be:

```
sed -i.json "2i\\
\"1.0.1\": \"1.0.1.zip\",
<Ctrl-Q><Tab>" file.json
```

where the `<Ctrl-Q><Tab>` sequence means pressing those specific keys. This will depend on the editor that you are using. In the comments you mention that you are using VS Code, so instead of the `<Ctrl+Q><Tab>` trick you might want to use one of the options given in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566785/vscode-insert-tab-character-manually

Note also that there is no space between `-i` and `.json`.

Comment: that doesn't work on mac. i get the error: `command i expects \ followed by text` the examples i see use single quotes like this in the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631989/sed-insert-line-command-osx. but it doesn't work with the double quotes like you posted. would be glad to try something else?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot that when you use double quotes you also need to escape the backslashes and add additional backslashes to the double quotes in the string itself. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Never mind that... what needed escaping was just the initial backslash. Try it now.

Comment: Did the last edit work? If so I would appreciate it if you marked it as the answer.

Comment: sed works in that i can replace the text i want. but my question was how to insert a tab with sed at a specific line. but yes i do mark questions as answered once they are answered.

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry about that, I got wrapped up with getting the quote characters right rather than in how to enter the tab character. Is this better?

Comment: I’m not sure if I u sweat and the tab part. I’m running this sed command as part of a script so I don’t think those commands work. That’s why I was trying the printf route.

Comment: it will work (I tried it) but how exactly to insert the tab depends on the editor that you're using. I usually use vim but it works on emacs too. nano doesn't need the `Ctrl+Q` at all. Which editor do you use?

Comment: I’m just editing that sed command in vs code

Comment: OK, that complicates things a bit, vs code doesn't support quoting. You might try one of these solutions instead of the `<Ctrl+Q><Tab>` trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566785/vscode-insert-tab-character-manually (copy and paste is probably easiest, but if you constantly need to insert tabs you might want to go with the keybinding)

Comment: so you are saying to open up vim, hit ctrl+q then tab, save it, then run that file? if that's what you mean, i tried it and it did not work. but at this point i'll just mark it as answered. thanks.

Comment: Just copy the tab character between the brackets on the second answer to the question I linked to, and paste it where you need it

Comment: Thanks for marking it, but I'd really like to help you solve your problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85100/discussion-between-crystal-and-mario-camou).

Comment: I updated my question with what I think you asked me to do with the output.